# Javascript Object Route Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

So I need to build an object that can map URL paths to target servers, like this:

```
/api         :   http://apiserver:8000
/api/v1      :   http://apiv1server:8888
/api/v1/foo  :   http://foo:8080
/foo         :   http://foo:8080
```

and

```
function addRoute(path, server) {
  setRoute(path, server)
}
addRoute('/api', 'http://apiserver:8000')
addRoute('/api/v1', 'http://apiv1server:8888')
```

Each lookup should match the most specific route, so my initial thinking was an object like this:

```
 let map = {
   api: {
     v1: {
       default: 'http://apiv1server:8000',
       foo: 'http://foo:8080'
     },
     default: 'http://apiserver:8000'
   },
   foo: 'http://foo:8080'
 }
```

So that you could use a simple lookup function like this:

```
function lookup(path) {
  let result = null
  path.split('/').forEach(key => {
    result = map[key] || map[key].default
  })
  return result
}
```

But trying to set an object through a dot (slash) notation has proven very difficult, any ideas?

Or is there another easier way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a simple mapping like `{'/api':   'http://apiserver:8000', '/api/v1': 'http://apiv1server:8888'}` ?

Comment: I need it to match the most specific route as well as longer routes match the longest matching prefix.

Answer (score 1):

```
function lookup(path){
   let arr = path.split("/").splice(1);
   let m = {...map};
   arr.forEach((e)=>{
      m = m[e] || m.default;
   })
  return typeof(m) === "object" ? m.default : m;
}
```

you can try this out.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it out, any idea out how to set a route?

Comment: are you using any framework like `express`, `koa` etc. they all have their unique way to handle `routes`. Or else you can declare routes using `http` `https` module also

Comment: I am using express, though I'm doing a dynamic node-proxy-middleware router as seen below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, since I couldn't find a great way to then set a route, I went to a recursive method below:

```
let RouteMap = function (def) {
  this.defaultRoute = def
  this.map = {}
}

RouteMap.prototype = {
  lookup: function (path) {
    console.log('ROUTE MAP LOOKUP: ', path)
    if (path) {
      let parts = path.split('/')
      let p = parts.shift()
      if (this.map[p] instanceof RouteMap) {
        return this.map[p].lookup(parts.join('/')) || this.defaultRoute
      } else {
        return this.map[p]
      }
    } else {
      return this.defaultRoute
    }
  },
  set: function (path, val) {
    console.log('ROUTE SET: ', path, val)
    if (path) {
      let parts = path.split('/')
      let p = parts.shift()
      if (parts.length > 0) {
        this.map[p] = this.map[p] || new RouteMap()
        this.map[p].set(parts.join('/'), val)
      } else {
        this.map[p] = val
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error('Path is', path)
    }
  },
  addRoutesFromEnv: function (env) {
    for (let key in process.env) {
      if (key.startsWith('SERVICE_')) {
        let val = process.env[key]
        let parts = val.split('::')
        if (parts.length === 2) {
          this.set(parts[0], parts[1])
          // this.add(parts[0], parts[1]) // /api/v1::http://v1host:8000
        } else {
          console.warn('Invalid SERVICE_NAME environment variable: should be SERVICE_NAME=/path/to/proxy::http://host:port, ', key)
        }
      }
    }

    console.log('ROUTE MAP: ', JSON.stringify(this.map, null, 2))
  }
}

module.exports = RouteMap
```